# error due to copying nltk from 1 python version to another

Tags: python, visual-studio, nltk

while in visual studio, I downloaded nltk for python 3.5, then downloaded python 2.7. Instead of installing `nltk` library again, I copied it and its `.dist-info` file to python 2.7 directory. Now, working in python 2.7' I'm getting an import warning error. `cElementTree.py` opens up automatically, displaying an error at `from element tree import` line. I did Intellisense/Refresh DB and checked Import warning in Open Exceptions Settings -didn't help. Ignoring this error, my program compiles, but seeing it every time I press F5 is annoying.

Comment: Let the package manager do the packaging, `pip3 install -U nltk` and `pip2 install -U nltk` or use `conda install nltk`. Do also read on virtual environments, see docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ . And if you're on windows, see https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Comment: Did you try in powershell?

Comment: using Virtual environment is the way to go. Solved everything for me.